# What im i missing to be able to import io.netty.handler.ssl.util.* if I already added the maven dependency?

Tags: java, maven, ssl, netty

I have a small Netty server, and im trying to follow the [chat](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/securechat) example.

I'm using maven and already added the dependency as follows:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.Alpha1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Now when I try to import `SelfSignedCertificate` or any other class from `io.netty.handler.ssl.util.` Eclipse complains, because it's not in the .jar file that was added by that dependency.

Any hint on what should i include? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version `5.0.0.Alpha1` is actually a pretty old version (December 22 2013).

According to [The Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22io.netty%22%20AND%20a%3A%22netty-all%22) the latest version of io.netty is `4.0.19.Final`, released on April 30 2014.

However, if you look at the [pom file](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/example/pom.xml) for the chat example program you can see that it's importing version `5.0.0.Alpha2-SNAPSHOT` of all the netty code.

A little further research shows that the [API docs](http://netty.io/5.0/api/index.html) for `5.0.0.Alpha2-SNAPSHOT` don't include that package, ***but*** if you go out to [github](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/handler/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/ssl/util) and look at the handler code you can see that the util package was added 24 days ago, and the example you linked shows as only 18 days old.

I think you're going to either have to wait for that package to be merged into a release, or go download and build `5.0.0.Alpha2-SNAPSHOT` yourself and install it locally.

Comment: I'll try to build it, but, i think i'll be better with just falling back to 4.x.x, right?

Comment: You still won't be able to compile anything depending on io.netty.handler.ssl.util using 4.x.x.  That package only exists in some SNAPSHOT code on github, it hasn't been released anywhere yet.

Comment: I did research that package, and it doesn't seem that it will be ever available. It looks that it is some util for testing, that won't be exported.